# Number of operations in grade school algorithm for multiplying 577 and 423

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, arithmetic

Given 577 x 423 with grade school algorithm you calculate

577 x 3 = 1731

577 x 2 = 1154

577 x 4 = 2308

*These are 3 multiplications of a number by a single digit.*

Then, you go on and add

1731 + 11540 = 13271

and then

13271 + 230800 = 244071 to get the result

*These are 2 additions.*

At the bottom line, this makes ~ 5 operations (of course depending on the number of digits you take, e.g., if you conceive the whole operation, it is just one multiplication, but this set aside).

In my copy of CC by Arora and Barak ([you can have a look at page xx](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521424267)) it says for this "3 multiplications of a number by a single digit and 3 additions". Is this an error? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this is an error. See Figure 1 on page 4 [here](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~reif/courses/complectures/books/AB/ABbook.pdf): only 2 additions are required.

Comment: Thank you! You are right. The same error is printed there on page 3 last sentence of the second paragraph. Wondering why nobody spotted it till 2006...

Comment: Note also that the $243071$ in Figure 1 should be $244071 \,(=423 \cdot 577)$.

Comment: This is true. In the final version of the book (as you can see from the amazon link), the result is corrected. So, someone must have looked over it, but did not correct the number of additions.